# v8: Concatenation of persistent string

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

If I have

`Nan::Persistent<String> persistedString`

and want to concatenate it with some `Local<String> localString`

do I need create a new local from persisted first, concat then rest the persistent?

```
Local<String> baseString = Nan::New(persistedString);
persistedString.reset(String::Concat(baseString, localString));
```

If so is this creating copy of persisted before concat? Or is it just referencing the memory?

Also is there a way to get string size out of `persistent<string>` without performing this operation?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, that is what you need to do.
- No, it does not create a copy of the persisted string, only a memory reference.
- No, you need a Local handle to do anything relevant.

Comment: Thanks. That would mean that when you invoke `dispose()` through `reset()` or `destructor()` all of the memory should be cleared? As I am seeing some behaviour that would say it doesn't also execution time on such is same as copying staff into `std::string`.